# Why is AWS.Lambda.invoke `error` callback argument never populated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm trying to invoke a lambda function from an external node.js app (i.e not on AWS).
I used code samples from the AWS documenattion and it works great for nominal cases.
However, in the case of an error, it never gets processed properly by my calling function.

My invocation code is as follow:

```js
    // AWS.config before
    
    var pullParams = {
        FunctionName : 'myFunctionName',
        InvocationType : 'RequestResponse',
        LogType : 'None',
        Payload : JSON.stringify({
            "myParam" : params
        })
    };

    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

    lambda.invoke(pullParams, function(error, data) {
        console.log("error value: " + error);
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error invoking AWS " + error);
            // process error
        } else {
            // process payload
        }
     });
```

In my lambda function, I raise an error if no params are provided and provide an error message

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var params = event.myParam;

    if (!params) {
        var error = new Error("Appropriate error message");
        callback(error);
        // In Node ≥8, could also be expressed making handler `async` and `throw`ing here
    }
    else {
        // do normal processing and create payload
        callback(null, "Payload");
    }
 }
```

However, in the `invoke` callback, `error` is always null (even when the lambda goes through the error code path), and when going through the error code path, then `data` contains `errorMessage, errorType, stackTrace` keys.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't the `invoke` binding  of `aws-sdk` populate `error` rather than making me check for `data.errorMessage` ?!

Comment: My question is... does `err` only get set when it fails to invoke it, and not when you return an error response? that seems to be the behavior you're seeing. I haven't used the javascript sdk to invoke lambda functions yet so i'm not sure of what's intended. [The docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) are somewhat unclear

Comment: Looking at the docs over [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) that seems to support the idea that returning an error from the function won't result in `err` being set and an error status code, and that the error you provide will be in the payload.

Comment: yes indeed; and it's not necessarily a bad way to do things; but the code samples such as [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/browser-invoke-lambda-function-full.html) would be incorrect, hence my suspicion that this approach is wrong

Comment: Filed [aws/aws-sdk-js issue #2134 - Lambda.invoke's `error` callback argument is never populated](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2134)

Answer (score 3):

I can use a workaround such as testing on the payload received:

//if (invocationError){

if (data.FunctionError){ <== null if no error, "Handled" if an error is returned

This technically works but its different from every code snipplet I found around.

Comment: This is what I've found. data.FunctionError exists on an error result, but the error object is null. Not quite sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by checking the data.Payload for an error message

```
 var pullParams = {
    FunctionName : 'myFunctionName',
    InvocationType : 'RequestResponse',
    LogType : 'None',
    Payload : JSON.stringify({
        "myParam" : params
    })
};

var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

lambda.invoke(pullParams, function(error, data) {
    console.log("error value: " + error);
    //data.Payload is returned as a string, to check it, turn into JSON object
    let payload = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error invoking AWS " + error);
        // process error
    } else {
        // process payload
        // check for Lambda error  
        if(!payload.errorMessage) {
             console.log(data.Payload);
        } else {
            //Lambda error
            console.log(payload.errorMessage);
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use context.fail() instead of callback(err) to get handler failing

Comment: `context.fail()` is the old, deprecated method. `callback(err)` is the new recommended method.

Comment: And using context.fail brings the same result. InvocationError is always null